# Which is operating systems considered safer Linux/Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are Linux-based operating systems considered safer than Windows?](https://serverfault.com/questions/35656/why-are-linux-based-operating-systems-considered-safer-than-windows)

Better for security /Hardware friendly /no need to shutdown for yr/ and which take lot of load in trumps of hit /easy admin /less patch work?

Comment: Ok, this looks like a loaded question from *every* possible angle.

Comment: There is no "safe" operating system! The only reason why Linux has been relatively safe was simply because it wasn't big enough as a target. The same with OS X. Sure, some hackers hack for fun but there are plenty of criminals out there who will go after the bigger targets where there's money. In general, that means Windows, since Windoes tends to be mostly used in commercial ways.

Answer (score 1):

OpenBSD, maybe.