# NTFS inherited permissions... from where?

Tags: security, ntfs, windows

I have a folder with special permissions for an user inherited from the "primary object", but the primary object isn't the normal hierarchical folder. How can I know which is the primary object for these permissions?

Example:

```
\Folder A (no special permissions for user Test)
    \Folder B (inherited special permissions for user Test)
```

So, inherited from where?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Are you talking about a disk folder or an AD folder? And if it's the latter, is it a folder or an OU?

Comment: Sorry the confussion, are disk folders

Comment: Please change the title then (to something including the word "NTFS"), as "Active Directory" contains folders too, so this is *quite* misleading.

Comment: [The inheritance issue](http://serverfault.com/questions/31709/how-to-workaround-the-ntfs-move-copy-design-flaw)?  Were these files moved?

Comment: Disc folders on a local disc or on a network drive?

Comment: It's a network drive, I don't know if these files were moved, maybe...

Comment: although it have been moved, I want to know which folder is the primary object, there is any way to do that?

Answer (score 4):

If you right click on Folder B and select the Security tab, then the Advanced button the Permissions tab displays a grid of permissions with an Inherited From column that should have the answer to your question.

Comment: It says "primary object", but I don't know wich is it.