# Permissions when copying/moving on the same volume on a Windows 2008 R2 server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, file-permissions, ntfs

Does http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310316 still apply to 2008 R2?

I see other questions here on SF like: [How to workaround the NTFS Move/Copy design flaw?](https://serverfault.com/questions/31709/how-to-workaround-the-ntfs-move-copy-design-flaw) that discuss the issue, but I was searching around to see if that KB article still was applicable to 2008 R2 or not.

Looking online I found another site: [How file and folder permissions are handled while moving or copying files on Windows 2008 R2 and Windows 7](http://www.winplat.net/post/2011/04/08/How-file-and-folder-permissions-are-handled-while-moving-or-copying-files-on-Windows-2008-R2-and-Windows-7.aspx)

[image]

Yet during **MY testing** I found that both *COPY* and *MOVE* worked the same, and inherited the destination parent folder's permissions and didn't retain the original permissions.  I tested with shares on the same server volume via a remote workstation.  Each share has completely different NTFS permissions.

So my questions are:

1. Can someone else with a 2008 R2 server verify what should/shouldn't happen with permissions when copying AND when moving files between folders on the same volume?
2. Is the KB article in the first sentence still applicable to 2008 R2 (even though it doesn't mention 2008 at all)

Answer (score 1):

> I tested with shares on the same server volume via a remote
>   workstation

From the remote workstation's point of view, the shares are seen as different volumes. Because they are going to be treated as different volumes, with Win7/2k8R2, it will thus inherit the permissions of the destination directory.

How is the remote computer supposed to know the file server's storage design or if the two shares are on the same underlying volume on the file server? If it connecting to DFS shares, they might even be on different servers.

Comment: Rex, I dealt with this briefly on the same server last week and found that 2 different files that were moved from one shared folder to another (same volume on the server, again from a remote workstation), and they kept their original permissions.  Yet my new tests show different results than that.  Reading the SF question that is linked, you can see that they experience the same, that remote users accessing server shares end up with the issue.